# JSF Lifecycle executed multiple times

Tags: jsf, lifecycle

I noticed that loading my page in InternetExplorer and Chrome triggers the JSF-Lifecycle upto 3 times, because there are multiple HTTP-Requests fired. My Debug Output is however just present in the first life-cycle. (For Firefox there is exactly one lifecycle)

Since the problem is not present in Firefox, i assume, that it is not a server-side problem(attaching a phaselistener 2 times could be one for example)

So, there need to be some calls by Chrome and IE that are causing an request to some server ressource where actually no one is needed.

The big question is: WHAT kind of components / tags may cause another HTTP-request, and why does it work in Firefox without those additional requests? **I read that a image-tag without url attribute may cause such a behaviour, because the browser is requesting the index-file again.** However Chrome's Network diagnostic doesn't show any invalid images neither a double request to one of the xhtml-sites.

IE-Example:

```
13:56:14,046 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-18) -- Started Request --
13:56:14,046 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-18) ---- Started RESTORE_VIEW 1 ----
13:56:14,048 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-18) ---- Started RENDER_RESPONSE 6 ----
13:56:14,100 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-18) xybean constructed
13:56:14,712 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-18) -- Finished Request --
13:56:15,106 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) -- Started Request --
13:56:15,106 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started RESTORE_VIEW 1 ----
13:56:15,108 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2 ----
13:56:15,110 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3 ----
13:56:15,111 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4 ----
13:56:15,112 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 ----
13:56:15,114 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) ---- Started RENDER_RESPONSE 6 ----
13:56:15,115 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-10) -- Finished Request --
```

Same Page call in Firefox:

```
14:03:33,443 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-2) -- Started Request --
14:03:33,443 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-2) ---- Started RESTORE_VIEW 1 ----
14:03:33,444 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-2) ---- Started RENDER_RESPONSE 6 ----
14:03:33,496 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-2) xybean constructed
14:03:34,258 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-2) -- Finished Request --
```

Comment: This is not a JSF problem. JSF doesn't create requests. It's the client who does that. IE is effectively sending 2 HTTP requests. Does it still do that if you disable JavaScript in IE? If not, then you got the root cause. Most likely there's somewhere a `form.submit()` call or a XHR POST request which is executed during document ready. Further, the usage of the term "lifecycle" is also incorrect and confusing in your question. In general, you actually meant to say "HTTP request". I recommend to revise your question.

Comment: @BalusC If client is creating more than 1 HTTP request, how can that be handled? One cannot expect end Users to disable Java Script. End user may not even know such feature in browsers. If I find `form.submit()` or a XHR POST request executed during document ready, what fix should be done?

Comment: @VikasV: uhm, disabling JS is just a quick test to nail down the root cause :) As to what should be done depends on the root cause of the problem and the business requirements, both which are completely unclear as of now.

Comment: @BalusC thx for the hint. I disabled image loading in IE and now there is just one HTTP-Request, triggering one JSF-Lifecycle (better wording? :-) ) So it has to do something with the images as mentioned in the post - even if all of them are shown and loaded correctly. I'll crosscheck the page and see if I can find the apple with worms.

Comment: @dognose Please do let us know once you fix it. As me too facing the same problem :)

Comment: @VikasV: Found it: I declared 2 favicons (ico/png) that were missing. this caused the 2 requests. (Im not sure about the reason, but maybe favicons are handled different by the browsers, and generating an error-response invokes the application and therefore one lifecycle per request - maybe BalusC can tell us :P )

Answer (score 1):

The Solution was quite simple:

I declared 2 favicons:

```
<!-- For Modern Browsers -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicons/favicon.png" />

<!-- For everything else -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/favicons/favicon.ico" />
```

in web.xml I declared my servlet-mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, IE and Chrome have been looking for `http://localhost/myApp/faces/img/favicons/favicon.png` and invoked the servlet by doing so. Changing the favicons to absolute urls (leaving the faces out) fixed the problem.

Maybe it would also be a good idea to change the url-pattern for the Faces Servlet to something more specific like `*.xhtml` or whatever file types you want to invoke it for.

Comment: *maybe favicons are handled different by the browsers*, last day I got this interesting blog entry about favicon and browser behavior (take special note about IE favicon handling): [Understand the Favicon](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/)